# spring data jpa query select all rows if given parameter collection is null

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, oracle11g, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to write a query that selects all rows by given type collection for my fileRepository(There are 3 types as "1", "2" and "3"), if that parameter is not given from frontend, then it should return all rows.

I am using a Repository with @RepositoryRestResource annotation to achieve this.
It works fine for single type query(not Collection)

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM #{#entityName} t WHERE :fileType IS NULL OR t.fileType = :fileType")
Page<MyFile> findByFileType(@Param("fileType") String fileType, @Param("page") Pageable pageable);
```

it returns all entities when I don't give any arguments i.e : "http://localhost:8080/api/myFiles/search/findByFileType"

and returns all Files which have type "1" when I search with 1 parameter:
"http://localhost:8080/api/myFiles/search/findByFileType?fileType=1"

But problem occurs when I try to write a query from collection of types and I tried this

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM #{#entityName} t WHERE :fileTypes IS NULL OR t.fileType IN :fileTypes")
Page<MyFile> findByFileType(@Param("fileTypes") Collection<String> fileTypes, @Param("page") Pageable pageable);
```

It still works for the example localhost links that I gave above but multiple parameter throws "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator" error with this link:
"http://localhost:8080/api/myFiles/search/findByFileType?fileType=1,2"

Edit: I am using Oracle11g as database.

Comment: so what is the SQL???? in the log of your chosen JPA provider. You can't hope to debug such things without looking at what it is doing.